# How to know whether an android app allows System audio Capturing?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, audio-recording, screen-recording

I am building a screen recording application. I just want to know while recording a particular game on my phone, how to know whether the app is allowing the user to record the audio, so that I can show a toast or a dialog.